# org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.tss.friends_api.user.model.User

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, web-services, jax-rs

I am posting everything that I have done below, so please have a look at it.

I don't know where the mistake is, and an Unknown entity error is showing. I even mapped a model in hibernate configuration file(hibernate.cfg.xml)

Resource Class in REST:

```
package com.tss.friends_api.user.resource;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

import com.tss.friends_api.user.model.User;
import com.tss.friends_api.user.service.UserService;
import com.tss.friends_api.user.service.UserServiceImpl;

@Path("user")
public class UserResource {

    UserService userService=new UserServiceImpl();
    @Path("/test")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String createUser(){
        return "user";
    }
    @POST
    @Path("")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response addUser(User user,@Context UriInfo uriInfo) throws Exception{
        if(user==null) throw new Exception();
        System.out.println(user);
        String string=userService.addUser(user);
        if(string!=null) {
        return Response.created(uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path(user.getUserId()+"").build()).entity("account created").build();

        }
        return null;

    }
```

Model class:

```
package com.tss.friends_api.user.model;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="user_id",nullable=false)
    private int userId;
    @Column(name="user_name")
    private String userName;
    @Column(name="user_emailid")
    private String userEmailId;
    @Column(name="user_contactnumber")
    private long userContactNumber;
    @Column(name="user_password")
    private String userPassword;
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,targetEntity=Friends.class,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Friends> userFriends;
    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getUserEmailId() {
        return userEmailId;
    }
    public void setUserEmailId(String userEmailId) {
        this.userEmailId = userEmailId;
    }
    public long getUserContactNumber() {
        return userContactNumber;
    }
    public void setUserContactNumber(long userContactNumber) {
        this.userContactNumber = userContactNumber;
    }
    public List<Friends> getUserFriends() {
        return userFriends;
    }
    public void setUserFriends(List<Friends> userFriends) {
        this.userFriends = userFriends;
    }
    public String getUserPassword() {
        return userPassword;
    }
    public void setUserPassword(String userPassword) {
        this.userPassword = userPassword;
    }


}
```

Hibernate.cgx.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/restws</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">anil4100</property>

        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <mapping package="com.tss.friends_api.user.model"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

UserService class:

```
package com.tss.friends_api.user.service;

import com.tss.friends_api.user.dao.UserDao;
import com.tss.friends_api.user.dao.UserDaoImpl;
import com.tss.friends_api.user.model.User;

public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    UserDao userDao=new UserDaoImpl();

    @Override
    public String addUser(User user) {
        return userDao.addUser(user);
    }
```

UserDao class:

```
package com.tss.friends_api.user.dao;

    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

    import com.tss.friends_api.user.model.User;

    public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
        public UserDaoImpl() {
            Configuration configuration=new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();
            sessionFactory=configuration.buildSessionFactory();
        }
        @Override
        public String addUser(User user) {
            Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
            return session.save(user)+"";
        }
```

and finally the error(short form):

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.tss.friends_api.user.model.User

Comment: I used postman to send requests when I hit request with json(user) input it is showing error unknown entity

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.tss.friends_api.user.model" });
```

to your `sessionFactory` in the `UserDaoImpl`.

I could imagine your `Hibernate.cgx.xml` gets ignored, because you build your own `sessionFactory` in the `UserDaoImpl`.

If you are using spring, have a look [here](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-mappingexception-unknown-entity) .